# Link to the Blog missing

Tags: bug, feature-request

Now that we have the new blog for cooking.stackexchange.com if a user is not logged in there is a link to blog (located in the hlinks-nav span), once the user is logged in the link is missing.

Based on a comment from derobert, perhaps the link is currently configured to only appear when there is new content.

I would think we want that link to persist, with a flag to show if there is new content.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140556/the-community-bulletin-is-not-good-enough-for-promoting-community-blog-posts/140591 — we're trying to get them to change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design, see [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94634/why-is-there-a-blog-link-but-only-for-guests). This policy is consistent over the network, and I doubt that they would change it for us. I guess that regular users with an account are supposed to know that the site has a blog. Also, there is a link in the footer navigation which doesn't disappear for users who are logged in.

The new Community Bulletin also shows blog posts when they are published, and specifies each link as "meta" or "blog". We moderators can manually create a link in the Community bulletin as long as the target is within the Stack Exchange network, and it stays there for the period of time we define. Blog links are inserted automatically when a new post is published, but I don't know how long it stays there. When there are no manually "pinned" links, the community bulletin is populated with random meta questions. I guess I could pin the last blog post for a longer time manually, but this creates the problem of a getting-used-to-effect: people may get used to seeing a "blog" type link on the community bulletin and not notice when it changes. If it is mostly populated with meta links but displays a blog link when there is a new post, users could be more likely to notice the change.

**UPDATE: This answer is no longer correct**. The link to the blog is never shown in the upper navigation bar any more. When there is a blog post, the community bulletin gets updated and shows the post. The link to the blog is still present on the bottom.

Comment: exactly, I saw the link (with a bright "New" tag) and then expected it to be there next time. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: -1 not because you're wrong, but because this seems really silly. I would think that the blog would hold far more interest for most of our readers than chat or meta. I also hate context dependent menus, because it makes me feel like I'm losing my mind when I don't understand the logic behind it (which is almost never obvious).

Comment: It's one thing to know that the site has a blog: it's another to have it bookmarked. I had to use Ctrl-F to find a link to it in the footer, after looking fruitlessly in the header and right column. This is a crazy policy.